# Windows XP change the order of IP address in a NIC having multiple ip address

Tags: windows-xp, lan, network-adapter, ip-address, window

I've a NIC with two IP address. Now how can I change the order of the IP address so that I can bring any one to the top and have precedence over the other IP addresses.

I know I can change that from going to the network properties but I was looking for a more faster way of doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking, but you can use the netsh command to change your ip address.  Again, not sure this is what you're looking for, but you can make this into a batch file if it is.  Syntax of the command from Microsoft

"netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static ipaddr subnetmask gateway metric"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257748

Comment: Look the first IP address in the advanced IP address list takes precendence. I want to change the order when there are multiple IP address assigned to a single adapter.